# пишет : error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char ' to binary 'operator+ (только начал изучать С++)

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b = (a + 1);
    int c = (a + 2);
    cin >> a;
    cout << "The next number for the number " + a + " is " + b << "\n" "The previous number for the number" + a " is " + c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: да тут всё не так. 1 - для таких строк + не работает. 2 - b и c содержат мусор (если не UB вообще).

Comment: у меня задача написать на вводе 179 а получить (The next number for the number 179 is 180.
The previous number for the number 179 is 178.)

Comment: Можно 1) использовать вместо `+` `<<`; 2) использовать [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf); 3) использовать [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) (`std::print` в будущем). Про UB @pavel верно написал. Сначала читайте `a`, а потом уже инициализируйте `b` и `c`.

Comment: Спасибо исправил ошибку

Comment: С каких это пор `a+2` предшествует `a`?...

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "The next number for the number " << a << " is " << a+1 
         << "\nThe previous number for the number " << a << " is " << a-1 << "\n";
}
```

Обратите внимание, что у вас сначала вычисляются значения `b` и `c` для какого-то неопределенного значения `a`, а только затем считывается само значение `a`. Так что не удивляйтесь, например, выводу

```
The next number for the number 178 is 24453 
The previous number for the number 178 is 24454
```

И, кстати, числу `a` предшествует `a-1`, а не `a+2`...